# In GCE, where can I find the files I have created from another device?

Tags: debian, google-compute-engine

I have connected to GCE from `ssh` and made some directories through `mkdir` command.

When I connect from another device (same credentials, instance), I see no directories exist. When go back to the same device where I created my directories, I see them.  Why is that? How can I get both devises to access the same directories.

Answer (score 1):

The files or directories that you create on the VM instances will remain on the disk of that VM. If you have created the files in the home directory of a one user and you ssh to the instance with another user you will need root access to see the files. You can use sudo -i to change your user to root and than will be able to read or copy the files from that directory.

Comment: nothing shows up after being root. still there are no files

Comment: What image you are using e.g centos, debian. Also how are you getting connected to the instance using ssh client or gcloud tool?

Comment: debian . connect through gcloud (i.e.  gcloud compute --project ..etc).. I must say I am in the free trial. if this changes anything

Comment: can you run this command 'gcloud compute disks describe <DISK-NAME> | grep image' and get the the complete image details e.g "backports-debian-7-wheezy-v20141108". I will try to reproduce the issue on my side.

Comment: In the website I have the same (Disks->instance-> Source image )

Comment: gcloud compute --project "xxxxx" disks describe backports-debian-7-wheezy-v20141108 | grep image
For the following disks:
 - [backports-debian-7-wheezy-v20141108]
choose a zone:
(9) us-central1-f   ... It gives me ERROR: (gcloud.compute.disks.describe) Could not fetch resource:
 - The resource 'projects/xxxxx/zones/us-central1-f/disks/backports-debian-7-wheezy-v20141108' was not found

Comment: I was not able to reproduce the issue. This is what I have done.

1. Created an instance with image backports-debian-7-wheezy-v20141108. 
2. ssh to the instance using terminal with user A and created few files using touch file1 and directories using mkdir dir1.
3. Used another computer and used putty to ssh into the instance using a different user B.
4. Did ls /home/userA and was able to see file1 and dir1

Comment: In this command gcloud compute disks describe <DISK-NAME> | grep image' you need to add your DISK-NAME which has the image installed. You can find the disk in your project using 'gcloud compute disks list'